# ¿Como crear y descargar un zip en la ruta localhost de apache?

Tags: java, ajax, tomcat, zip

Tengo una aplicación web en **java 8** desplegada en un **apache tomcat 9** y necesito que, al dar clic en un botón de una jsp, se genere una carpeta con varios .pdf esta se comprima y luego se descargue automáticamente, ya llego hasta el punto de generar el .zip, pero no sé cómo hacer para que se descargue. Había pensado en generar él .zip en la carpeta webapp o en una carpeta temporal que pueda eliminar diariamente. por medio de un ajax hacer la petición desde la jsp y que el servlet me devuelva la url, despues usar `window.open(result.url, "_blank");` para generar la descarga pero no sé cómo declarar el path o la ruta relativa en la clase que genera y guarda el archi .zip

La ruta que quisiera obtener es algo como `localhost:8080/miaplicacio/capertatemporal/miarchivo.zip`

Comment: tienes que leer el path url del zip y escupirlo como un stream en el header para que el navegador sepa que en lugar de recibir una respuesta en formato html recibirá un archivo de descarga... la otra opciones es brindarle al usuario un link de descarga del archivo o enviárselo por correo ... hay varias formas de hacerlo ... pero realmente si quieres que te ayuden en el sitio, creo que deberías de agregar el código de lo que hayas hecho ...

Comment: pues es que para añadir todas las clases es complicado, pero basicamente es como puedo almacenar una carpeta en localhost y que pueda acceder a ella desde el navegador

Comment: eso es lo que tienes que investigar ...